transfer invoice info from the entry sheet to the data sheet by apps script in google sheets
I wrote a code that transfer the info from the entry sheet to the data sheet,
the problem is the invoice in the entry sheet may contain 100 rows to transfer,
and when I try this way the program became slower when the user write more than 10 rows.
function Entry() {
  var SS=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var EE=SS.getSheetByName("entry");
  var DataSheet=SS.getSheetByName("data");
  var Blankrow=DataSheet.getLastRow()+1;
  var Blankrow2=DataSheet.getLastRow()+2;
  var Blankrow3=DataSheet.getLastRow()+3;
  var Blankrow4=DataSheet.getLastRow()+4;
 
  var EE2=EE.getRange("D6").getValue();
  var EE3=EE.getRange("D7").getValue();
  var EE4=EE.getRange("D8").getValue();

  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow,1).setValue(EE.getRange("D3").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow,2).setValue(EE.getRange("F3").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow,3).setValue(EE.getRange("D5").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow,4).setValue(EE.getRange("E5").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow,5).setValue(EE.getRange("G5").getValue());
  
  if(EE2!=""){
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow2,1).setValue(EE.getRange("D3").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow2,2).setValue(EE.getRange("F3").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow2,3).setValue(EE.getRange("D6").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow2,4).setValue(EE.getRange("E6").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow2,5).setValue(EE.getRange("G6").getValue());
  }
  if(EE3!=""){
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow3,1).setValue(EE.getRange("D3").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow3,2).setValue(EE.getRange("F3").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow3,3).setValue(EE.getRange("D7").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow3,4).setValue(EE.getRange("E7").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow3,5).setValue(EE.getRange("G7").getValue());
  }
if(EE4!=""){
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow4,1).setValue(EE.getRange("D3").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow4,2).setValue(EE.getRange("F3").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow4,3).setValue(EE.getRange("D8").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow4,4).setValue(EE.getRange("E8").getValue());
  DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow4,5).setValue(EE.getRange("G8").getValue()); 
  }

  EE.getRange("D3").clearContent();
  EE.getRange("H3").clearContent();
  EE.getRange("J3").clearContent();
  EE.getRange("D5:D23").clearContent();
  EE.getRange("E5:E23").clearContent();
  EE.getRange("G5:G23").clearContent();
}

I want a way that make the code run faster.

I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and the problem is the invoice in the entry sheet may contain 100 rows to transfer, and when I try this way the program became slower when the user write more than 10 rows.. And, the ranges of clearContent() is always constant as showing in your script? Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Sorry, The script actually is longer than that it's contain the transfer operation for all the 100 rows of values, because the user may entry up to 100 rows of data, I used the if statement because I want the function to transfer only the filled cells not all the 100 rows, and the ranges of clearcontent() is constant because it doesn't matter if the function clear all the cells or just the cells are filled with values

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script. Please confirm it.

I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to reduce the process cost of your script.
In your actual situation, there are 100 lines of the script like DataSheet.getRange(Blankrow,1).setValue(EE.getRange("D3").getValue());.
The ranges of clearContent() is always constant of "D3", "H3", "J3", "D5:E23", "G5:G23".

In this case, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
function Entry2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("entry");
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("data");
  var srcLastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();
  var [[d3, , f3], , ...srcValues] = srcSheet.getRange("D3:G" + srcLastRow).getValues();
  var temp = Array(5).fill(null);
  var dstValues = srcValues.map(([d, e, , g]) => d.toString() ? [d3, f3, d, e, g] : temp);
  if (dstValues.length == 0) return;
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setValues(dstValues);
  srcSheet.getRangeList(["D3", "H3", "J3", "D5:E23", "G5:G23"]).clearContent();
}


In your script,for example, when if(EE2!="") is false, the row of var Blankrow2=DataSheet.getLastRow()+2 is empty. I modified your script by reflecting on this.

Note:

When I tested your showing script using a simple sample Spreadsheet, I confirmed that the result of my modified script was the same as your script. But, if that was not your expected result, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.


i really appreciate it, that helped me a lot, but I'm afraid I can't confirm your answer because I am a new member here.

@Data Analyst Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
